# How to create a dialog to select multiple files using winapi?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, windows-7

How can I create normal file open dialog with multifile selection possibility? I am using the GetOpenFileName() function to open a dialog.

If I set `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT` to the `Flags`, it will give me this kind of dialog:

[image]

It is not what I want for multiple reasons.

I want it to look similar to this:
[image]

Is there any simple/easy solution, or do I have to re-create the whole dialog myself?

**Edit:** here is my code to open the dialog:

```
OPENFILENAME ofn;
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
ofn.lpstrFile = "selectfile";
ofn.nMaxFile = 260;
ofn.lpstrFilter = "t1\0test1\0t2\0test2\0";
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
ofn.Flags = OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
ofn.lpstrTitle = TEXT("title");
GetOpenFileName(&ofn);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must include the `OFN_EXPLORER` flag as well as the `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT` flag.

The downside of using `GetOpenFileName` is that you have to allocate the buffer for the selected files. And so this means that you need to decide in advance of showing the dialog how large the buffer should be. This has the effect of limiting the number of files that can be selected.

On Vista and later you can use the [common item dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb776913.aspx) instead of `GetOpenFileName`. One of the many improvements of the new common item dialog is that the caller does not allocate the buffer. And so there is no limit to the number of files that can be selected.

---

A rather serious problem with your code is that you did not allocate a buffer. You wrote:

```
ofn.lpstrFile = "selectfile";
```

which supplies a read-only string literal instead of a mutable buffer. You will need to fix that problem before proceeding. This code shows the bare minimum needed to bring up a file dialog with support for multiple select:

```
OPENFILENAME ofn = { sizeof ofn };
wchar_t file[1024];
file[0] = '\0';
ofn.lpstrFile = file;
ofn.nMaxFile = 1024;
ofn.Flags = OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_EXPLORER;
GetOpenFileName(&ofn);
```

Comment: That did the trick. The weird thing is that I managed to crash the program (after quitting) once I added `OFN_EXPLORER` to the example code. But in my full code it seems to work fine for some reason. Maybe the extensions list was incorrectly generated (I use own function to do that in the full version).

Comment: Yes, the example code has a nasty bug that I cover in the second part of my answer.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I was afraid my code had bigger problems. I created the code snippet from full version to provide as minimal "working" code as possible.

Comment: That's fine. You did well to make a nice short example, much appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, the idiomatic way to initialise the struct goes like this: `OPENFILENAME ofn = { sizeof ofn };` That sets the first member, and default initialises all the other members.

Comment: I guess that only works in this struct. I try to avoid too fancy ways (ways that only work in specific cases), to prevent my copypaste errors in future. Thanks anyway, I wondered what was that doing.

Comment: @Rookie No, it's a language feature that works always. It's really not fancy at all.

Comment: I mean, if I do that on my own struct sometime, but then later change the order of the variables... Mysterious things will happen. Thats why I like explicit struct initializations more.

Comment: I'd use this only for structs with a size field. Which by convention is always first.

Comment: Yes, but how do you know it has the size fields... I wouldnt be able to remember those things myself.

Comment: I understand your point of view. At the very least, default initialise it like this: `OPENFILENAME ofn = { 0 };` That's much better than a call to `ZeroMemory`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think I will use that. I had a vague memory of those not working sometimes. Gotta test.

Comment: Looks like it works like a charm! I think the problem I had with that kind of initialization was non-static array initialization such as `int test[111] = {0};` which would not initialize more than the first element into 0. But when you make it as `static int test[111] = {0}`, then it should work IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

open file dialog with multiselect, working example

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
OPENFILENAME ofn={0};
char szFile[MAX_PATH + 1] = {0};
char szDirect[MAX_PATH + 1] = {0}; 
int fCount=0;   

switch(iMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    return 0;

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    //(int)wParam - virtual key code, lParam - key data
    switch((int)wParam)
        {
        case VK_ESCAPE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        
        case VK_F1:
        ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
        ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;   
        ofn.lpstrFile = szDirect;
        *(ofn.lpstrFile) = 0;
        ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
        
        //file type filter, \0 - null character (end of string)
        ofn.lpstrFilter = "All Files\0*.*\0Compressed Zip\0*.ZIP\0Text .txt\0*.TXT\0";
        
        ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
        ofn.lpstrFileTitle = szFile;
        *(ofn.lpstrFileTitle) = 0;
        ofn.nMaxFileTitle = sizeof(szFile);
        ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
        ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT;

        //show dialog Open
        if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn)==TRUE) 
        {
        printf("files selected\n");
        char* ptr = ofn.lpstrFile;
        ptr[ofn.nFileOffset-1] = 0;
        printf("Directory path: %s\n", ptr);
        ptr += ofn.nFileOffset;
        
        while (*ptr)
            {
            fCount++;           
            printf("File: %i %s\n", fCount, ptr);
            ptr += (lstrlen(ptr)+1);
            }
            
        printf("\n");               
        printf("selected %i files\n", fCount);  
        }
        else
        {
        printf("no files selected\n");
        }
        
        break;
        case VK_F2:
        //GetSaveFileName() for example 
        break;          
        }
    break;  

    case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
    }

return DefWindowProc(hwnd, iMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
//class name
static char szAppName[] = "HelloWin";
HWND hwnd;
MSG msg;

//declare class variable wc 
WNDCLASS wc;
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wc.cbClsExtra = 0; wc.cbWndExtra = 0; wc.hInstance = hInstance; 
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); 
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground =(HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = szAppName;

//register class variable wc 
RegisterClass(&wc);

//create window
hwnd = CreateWindow
(szAppName, "Standard Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
100, 100, 600, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

//show window
ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hwnd);

while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
  {
  TranslateMessage(&msg);
  DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
return msg.wParam;
}
```

[image]